# How to configure apache httpclient 4.5+ SSLContext to use mutual TLS authentication with a self signed certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, tls1.2

I am trying to configure a `CloseableHttpClient` from httpclient 4.5 with mutual TLS authentication. The server certificate is self-signed.
Here is the code I use (inpired by various StackOverflow posts):

```java
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ssl_cert_file)) {
    trustStore.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
}
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadKeyMaterial(trustStore, password.toCharArray(), (map, socket) -> "client")
        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
        .build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,  new DefaultHostnameVerifier());
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register("https", socketFactory).build();
connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
```

I Got

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Which looks like that the CA certificate I provide is not used I think.
Any idea of what could be wrong ?

---

The CA's certificate, client's certificate and client's private key are in a pkcs12 file
generated with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey private/client-key.pem -certfile cacert.pem -name "client" -out client-cert.p12
```

I tried `openssl s_client` to check the certificate return the expected output (it does). I suspect the problem is coming from my code rather than the `client-cert.p12` file.

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -tls1 -cert client-cert.pem -key private/client-key.pem -CAfile cacert.pem
```

Comment: Using the JDK keytool you can check what is in your truststore. `keytool -list -v -keystore filename.p12`. The server certificate chain entries should appear as entry type TrustedCertEntry. Are they?

Comment: No i only have :
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
...
Although inspecting the loaded Keystore object in debug i can see keystore => CertificateCount = 2

Comment: Thanks for the your comment it really hepls! Do you know how to correctly generate a p12 file containing my CA cert as a TrustedCertEntry ?

Comment: Humm I coul improve things a litle bit by generating a `.jks` file for the CA's cert. however I now have: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Broken pipe (Write failed)`. Note that putting the trust strategy to TrsutAllStrategy it works, so the pb is related to the CA's certificate not the client certificates I think.

Comment: Okay I introduced a typo in my code where I give the alias's entry of the client certificate. Everything woks as expected. Would be great to know how to correctley generate / use the pkcs12 file though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by @Gimby The problem was my CA's certificate was not recognized as a TrustCertEntry in my keystore.

My workaround is to generate a jks file just for the CA's certificate:

```
keytool -import -alias client -file cacert.pem -storetype JKS -keystore cacert.jks
```

Build a KeyStore object from it and use it for `SSLContext.loadTrustMaterial`.

Comment: Good, unfortunately I had no time to further expand on it. I would recommend you to split your key materials into a keystore and your trust materials into a truststore, so two stores instead of one. Then pass the appropriate store to loadKeyMaterial() an loadTrustMaterial(). Keeping the key and trust materials separate from each other will make you-two-years-from-now be very grateful to you.

Comment: Yes this is what i did. Thanks again.